# Long retry in azure datafactory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

We have a requirement of retry the particular slice after 1 hour if validation failed.
I gone through the Azure ADF docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-create-pipelines) and got option of **longRetry** but its not working as expected.

**Policy validation in input dataset:-**

```
 "policy": {
            "validation": {
                "minimumSizeMB": 0.000005
            }
        }
```

**Long retry in pipeline:-**

```
 "policy": {
                    "concurrency": 1,
                    "retry": 3,
                    "longRetry": 2,
                    "longRetryInterval": "01:00:00"
                }
```

**Summary:-** We want to check validation of particular dataset every hour with pipeline having frequency daily once.

Please let me know if am doing anything wrong here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To work with **longRetry** we have to add some more property in dataset as below.

```
policy": {
            "validation": {
                "minimumSizeMB": 0.000005
            },
            "externalData": {
                "retryInterval": "01:00:00",
                "maximumRetry": 4
            }
```